# Ionic 2 - Duplicate Identifier

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I just downloaded the Ionic 2 sample project with TypeScript and wanted to make the following class:

```
export class Accomodation {
     private longitude:number;
     private latitude:number;
     private name:string;


    constructor(public long, public lat, public name) {
        this.longitude = long;
        this. latitude = lat;
        this.name = name;
    }


    get longitude():number {
        return this.longitude;
    }

    set longitude(value:number) {
        this.longitude = value;
    }

    get latitude():number {
        return this.latitude;
    }

    set latitude(value:number) {
        this.latitude = value;
    }

    get name():string {
        return this.name;
    }

    set name(value:string) {
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
    import  {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Accomodation} from "../model/Accomodation";



@Injectable()
export class LocationService{
     static getLocations(){
        var location1 = new Accomodation(10, 10, "A beautiful place");
        var location2 = new Accomodation(20, 20, "A wonderful place");

        var allLocations = [location1, location2];

        return Promise.resolve(allLocations);
    }
}
```

However, I run into errors:

```
****/Accomodation.ts
Error:(6, 14) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'longitude'.
Error:(7, 14) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'latitude'.
Error:(8, 14) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'name'.
Error:(11, 49) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'name'.
Error:(18, 9) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'longitude'.
Error:(22, 9) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'longitude'.
Error:(26, 9) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'latitude'.
Error:(30, 9) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'latitude'.
Error:(34, 9) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'name'.
Error:(38, 9) TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'name'.
```

I have no idea what is going on. Google Search didn't help
Any ideas what I could do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declaring the constructor like you did `constructor(public long, public lat, public name)`, is syntactic sugar for this:

```
public longitude:number;
public latitude:number;
public name:string;

constructor(longitude, latitude, name) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.name = name;
}
```

But you already declared those properties (as private), so the Typescript compiler sees two different declarations for each of them.

You can do one of the following:

```
private longitude:number;
private latitude:number;
private name:string;

constructor(long, lat, name) {
    this.longitude = long;
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.name = name;
}
```

or (without declaring anything first)

```
constructor(private longitude:number, private latitude:number, private name:string) {}
```

Also, it might be a problem that your getters/setters have the same name as the private properties. A common practice is to name the private properties with a `_` prefix.